# Getting syntax highlighting in shell and emacs via Terminal.app on mac os x

Tags: macos, unix, ssh, terminal

How could I enable syntax highlighting on the shell and in emacs when I use Terminal.app on Mac OS X to ssh into other machines?  Right now if I ssh and do an "ls" for example, directories are not shown in a different color from flat files, for example, and I'd like to fix that.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a .bashrc or similar on those machines that you are ssh'ing to? I believe that is what you need, with something like `alias ls="ls --color=auto"` or `alias ls="ls -G"`(depending on your ls) in each (for ls; there are lots of other options to do other colors with other terminal programs).

Answer (score 2):

In OS X, you need to add `alias ls="ls -G"` to your ~/.bash_profile file. The file is originally hidden, so you'll need to either show hidden files in the Finder or use a program like Textmate that can open hidden files.

Comment: Any program can open hidden files. Just press `Cmd-Shift-.` in the file dialog.

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea about that. Nice tip!